# CAML query to get items from SPList

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I wanted to update the Name field in a list which contain 'finance' in the department list. I wrote the following code but it updates every item in the Name column whether it contains 'finance' or not.

What am i doing wrong?

```
SPListItemCollection Items = RiskAssesment.GetItems(new SPQuery()
{
     Query = @"<where>
                   <Eq>
                       <FiledRef Name 'Department'/>
                       <Value Type='Text'>Finance </Value>
                   </Eq>
               </Where>"
});

foreach (SPListItem item in Items)
{
    item["Name"] = "abcdef";
    item.Update();
}
```

Comment: In your code you don't have the Typo in the query or ? FiledRef should be FieldRef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FiledRef** should be **FieldRef**. And you forgot the equal sign, it should be like this:

`<FieldRef Name='Department' />`

**Small edit:**
I'm not sure if CAML is case-sensitive, but in case it is: change the opening-where to `<Where>`.

Comment: I love the way CAML just returns the full result set if you mess your query up a little :-/

Comment: Just to be sure, if a query doesn't works, try to wrap it with a <Query></Query> tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
SPListItemCollection Items = RiskAssesment.GetItems(new SPQuery()
{
     Query = @"<Where>
     <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='Department'/>
         <Value Type='Text'>Finance </Value></Eq></Where>"
 });

  foreach (SPListItem item in Items)
  {
         item["Name"]="abcdef";
         item.Update();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below function get the folder name and id of subfolder where items stored
folder = item.folder.

Initially it will be null.

```
static string GetParentFolder(SPListItem itemToFind, SPFolder folder)  
        { 
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); 
           // query.Query =  "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy>";
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Integer\">"+ itemToFind.ID +"</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.Folder = folder;
            query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
            SPListItemCollection items = itemToFind.ParentList.GetItems(query);
            int intpartentFolderID=0 ;
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
            foreach (SPListItem item in items) 
            {

                SPFile f = item.Web.GetFile(item.Url);

                string test11 = f.ParentFolder.Name;
                intpartentFolderID = f.ParentFolder.Item.ID;

                //string test1 = item.File.ParentFolder.Name;

                 return (intpartentFolderID.ToString()); 

             }
            }
            return (intpartentFolderID.ToString());     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function get the folder name and id of subfolder where items stored
folder = item.folder. 
Initially it will be null.

```
static string GetParentFolder(SPListItem itemToFind, SPFolder folder)  
        { 
           SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); 
           // query.Query =  "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy>";
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Integer\">"+ itemToFind.ID +"</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.Folder = folder;
            query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
            SPListItemCollection items = itemToFind.ParentList.GetItems(query);
            int intpartentFolderID=0 ;
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
            foreach (SPListItem item in items) 
            {
                SPFile f = item.Web.GetFile(item.Url);

                string test11 = f.ParentFolder.Name;
                intpartentFolderID = f.ParentFolder.Item.ID;

                //string test1 = item.File.ParentFolder.Name;

                 return (intpartentFolderID.ToString()); 

             }
            }
            return (intpartentFolderID.ToString());     
        }
```

---

Thanks
Deva-  Cheraideva

Answer (score 0):

So I just came across this older post, and I don't have enough reputation to comment on the selected answer.

But I know that when using CAML is definitely case sensitive in SharePoint 2013.

Just means that the opening `<where>` should be `<Where>`.

Hope you got your issue solved!